# Check Internet connection state using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, afnetworking, nsnotificationcenter

I want to create common class for checking internet connection also it should notify me when internet changes its status.

I am using AFNetworking for checking internet status.

Here is my code i have tried but it is not working please help where i am making mistake??

`CheckInternet` is my common class derived from `NSObject`

**CheckInternet.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CheckInternet : NSObject

+ (void)startNetworkMonitoring;
+ (BOOL)isInternetConnectionAvailable;
@end
```

**CheckInternet.m**

```
#import "CheckInternet.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"

@implementation CheckInternet


+ (void)startNetworkMonitoring
{
    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        NSLog(@"Reachability: %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));

        // Check the reachability status and show an alert if the internet connection is not available
        switch (status) {
            case -1:
                // AFNetworkReachabilityStatusUnknown = -1,
                NSLog(@"The reachability status is Unknown");
                break;
            case 0:
                // AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable = 0
                NSLog(@"The reachability status is not reachable");
                break;
            case 1:
                NSLog(@"The reachability status is reachable via wan");
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reachabilityChanged" object:nil];
                break;
            case 2:
                // AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi = 2
                NSLog(@"The reachability status is reachable via WiFi");

                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reachabilityChanged" object:nil];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }];
}

#pragma mark - Check Internet Network Status
+ (BOOL)isInternetConnectionAvailable {
    return [AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable;
}

@end
```

In My `ViewController.m` (here i want to check internet status)

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];



     [CheckInternet startNetworkMonitoring];


    if ([CheckInternet isInternetConnectionAvailable])
    {
         NSLog(@"---- Internet YES------ ");
    }
    else
    {
         NSLog(@"----- Internet NO------ ");
    }
}

//This is not called...
- (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"---- reachabilityChanged ----");
}
```

***Thank you in advance!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend to start monitoring your network activity in the `AppDelegate`. Move `[CheckInternet startNetworkMonitoring];` to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Second, add the following line to `case == 0`:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reachabilityChanged" object:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:one]];
```

Also make sure, you post the status of your connection with the notification. Because it is an integer, you need to wrap it in an object (typically into NSNumber).

Third, you need to observe the `reachabilityChanged` notification.
Add this in your `viewDidLoad`.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) 
        name:@"reachabilityChanged"
        object:nil];
```

In your function `- (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)notification` you should be able to access the notification's userInfo property and read the state code there.

Also, do not forget to unobserve the notification once your viewController has disappeared. So in `dealloc`

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: how do i notify when internet goes on/off?

Comment: if you observe the `reachabilityChanged ` in your viewController, where you would like to be notified, than your function should be called.

Comment: awesome answer dude works perfectly.... but only one problem dealloc method of view controller is nt called

Comment: Do not worry about that, it is called, but by OS, and we are not really able to track it. Leave the code there, so when the VC is deallocating, it removes the observation too. Also, if it is working, maybe mark it as accepted answer?